# Why and when there are things I can not do in CLASS SCOPE in C#?

Tags: c#, class, variables, scope, intellisense

well... I'm confused about what can I do and what I can't do in CLASS SCOPE.

For example

=========================

```
class myclass
{


  int myint = 0;

  myint = 5; *// this doesnt work. Intellisense doesn't letme work with myint... why?*

  void method()
  {
    myint = 5; *//this works. but why inside a method?*
  } 
}
```

==================================

```
class class1
{ 
 public int myint;
}

class class2
{
  class1 Z = new class1();

  Z.myint = 5; *//this doesnt work. like Z doesnt exists for intellisense*

 void method()
  {
    Z.myint = 5; *//this Works, but why inside a method?*
  }
}
```

---

Thats I make so many mistakes, I dont understand what works on class scope and what doesnt work.

I know that there are local varaibles and its life cycle. But I dont understand the so well the idea.

Comment: You need to add a Constructor (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) if you want an alternative to Field Iinitializers

Comment: Also see (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(VS.71).aspx) for the Scoping Language Specification

Comment: This is a pretty basic question, so you shouldn't stop at reading our answers.  Instead, you would benefit from a beginner's tutorial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A class can only contain **declarations**, **initializations**, and **methods**. It cannot contain **statements** of its own.

```
class MyClass
{
    int x; // a declaration: okay
    int y = 5; // a declaration with an initialization: okay
    int GetZ() { return x + y; } // a method: okay

    x = y; // a statement: not okay
}
```

Comment: +1: Any "class scoped statements" required need to be placed within a constructor.

Comment: +1: Nothing "runs" the class, only methods (including ctors & properties) inside a class can be run.

Comment: We should probably note that properties count as methods here.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a field, but you can't just have assignment statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do the below:

```
class myclass
{
  int myint = 0;
  myint = 5;
```

Because there is nothing to do, you can only declare members and possibly set an initial value.  It is nothing to do with scope.  One of the reeasons you can't do it is that there is no guarantee of order, the compiler just gurantees all values will be initialised by the time the class is instantiated. That is why you also cannot do the following:

```
class myclass
{
  int myint = 0;
  int MyOtherInt = myint;
```

If you want to set the value when the class is instantiated, put it in the contructor.

Comment: But if the class has this order ?

class1
{
  int a;
  void method();
  int b;
}

Will be that order? a, method, b . ??? "b" can not be initialized before the "method" executes, right?

Comment: in a class definition, the methods do not execute you are just declaring them so in your example method will not execute at all.

Comment: But what do you mean about "there is no guarantee of order" ?

Comment: When you instantiate a class, there is no guarantee of the order that members are initialized in. The compiler simply guarantees that they will be initialised by the time the class is instantiate. From your posts and comments I suspect you don't really understand what a class is, I would recommend further reading.

Comment: I'm reading the most I can. I'm eating it step by step. But sometimes this questions rise up, and I need to ask them.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you create a class, you are not allowed to have code & assignments inside that class directly.

but as c# wants to help you, it allows you to define initial states for fields. and they are basically executed directly bevore your constructor code.

when you now want to define code inside the class. somewhere... the program would not know, when to execute. so they are forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

A class definition defines its makeup, that is, the fields, properties, methods, events, etc. that it contains.  The "work" is actually done inside methods.

What you seem to be confusing is the initialization of the fields of a class with the usage of those fields.  You can *initialize* a field outside a method definition, but to use it, you need to be inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

To clearly understand it and get answers on your questions you should read Jeffrey's Richter "CLR via C#, Third Edition" and [C# 4.0 Language Spectification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dfbf523c-f98c-4804-afbd-459e846b268e&displaylang=en)